# MS C++ linker questions

Tags: visual-c++, linker, linked-list

I have a copy of MS VC++ 6.0 which I do all my development in.  I have just received a DLL that has been produced by VC++ 8.0.  I need to use some of the functions contained in that DLL in my application.  Will I be able to use this DLL in my VC++ 6.0 development environment?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as the DLL is using a portable interface such as COM or C style exports.
C++ interfaces like CString is not portable (it changed from a class to a template after VC6).